# Popen: redirect stderr and stdout to single stream

Tags: python, stream, spark-submit

I have created a Wrapper around the Spark-Submit command to be able to generate real time events by parsing the logs.
The purpose is to create a Real Time interface showing detailed progress of a Spark Job.

So the wrapper will look like this:

```
  submitter = SparkSubmitter()
  submitter.submit('/path/to/spark-code.py')
  for log_event in submitter:
    if log_event:
      print('Event:', log_event)
```

And the output will look like the following:

```
  Event: StartSparkContextEvent()
  Event: StartWorkEvent()
  Event: FinishWorkEvent()
  Event: StopSparkContextEvent()
```

Internally, the SparkSubmitter class launches the spark-submit command as a subprocess.Popen process, and then iterators over the stdout stream and returns Events by parsing the logs generated by the process, like this:

```
  class SparkSubmitter():
    def submit(self, path):
        command = self.build_spark_submit_command(path)
      self.process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # note: this is a IO-Blocking command
        log = self.process.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8') 
      return self.parse_log_and_return_event(log)
```

This implementation works well with the Spark Standalone Cluster. But I am having a issue when running on a Yarn Cluster.

In the Yarn Cluster the "Spark Related Logs" are coming in the `stderr`, instead of `stdout`. So my class is not able to parse the spark generated logs because it is only trying to read the `stdout`.

**Question 1**: Is it possible to read Popen's stdout and stderr as a single stream?

**Question 2**: As stdout and stderr are both Streams, is it possible to merge both the streams and read them as one?

**Question 3**: Is it possible to redirect all the logs to only stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all 3 of your questions is yes, you can use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as an argument to `Popen` to redirect output from `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
self.process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: What is I still want to know, from which pipe every single line came: stderr or stdout?